# How to crop multi-ROIs as images in DM by scripting?

Tags: image-processing, roi, dm-script

I would like to crop these two ROIs as two images:

[image]

I am thinking to crop these two ROI synchronously by scripting, I found a code about creating image from ROI by D. R. G. Mitchell. So I wrote this:

```
image front := GetFrontImage()
imagedisplay imgdisp = front.ImageGetImageDisplay(0)
number roinum = imgdisp.ImageDisplayCountRois()
number x

for (x=0; x<roinum; x++)
{
roidisp = ImageDisplayGetROI(imgdisp,x)
image crop = front []
ShowImage(crop)
}
```

But it actually only works for one ROI. I'll appreciate if you could give me a clue about how to deal with more than one ROI's cropping. Thanks!

Comment: You are on the right track with your script, but when you get your ROI (as an object of type `ROI` you need to use it. The last two lines in your `for`-loop are completely independent of the ROI. See my example below. They are "simple coding" notation using the `[]` to address the areas highlighted by the front-most available rectangular, volatile ROI.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This example should help you:

```
// ROIs are objects of the image display, so get that one first
Image input := GetFrontImage()
ImageDisplay disp = input.ImageGetImageDisplay(0)

// Iterate over all ROIs found on the display
number nRoi = disp.ImageDisplayCountROIs()
for (number i=0; i<nRoi; i++ )
{
    ROI myRoi = disp.ImageDisplayGetROI( i )

    // Test if the ROI has the properties you want
    if ( !myROI.ROIIsRectangle() )  continue
    if ( !myROI.ROIGetVolatile() )  continue

    // Read the ROI region and use that to copy the data
    number t, l, b, r 
    myROI.ROIGetRectangle( t, l, b, r )

    // Use slice2 to address the area and ImageClone to get a clone
    // inclusing tags, calibration etc.
    image cut := input.Slice2(t,l,0, 0,(r-l),1, 1,(b-t),1 ).ImageClone()
    cut.ShowImage()

    // Optionally set some names
    cut.SetName( input.GetName()+" #"+(i+1) )

    // Optionally modify the roi
    myRoi.ROISetVolatile( 0 )
    myRoi.ROISetMoveable( 0 )
    myRoi.ROISetLabel( "cut #"+(i+1) )
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much! It works well! Sorry for late reply.